# Any good free SSL proxy on windows?

Tags: tls, windows, certificates, proxy

I'm looking for SSL proxy capable of dumping requests.

I want to test custom browser against SSL-MITM attacks.

I'm able to re-route all traffic ongoing from browser to machine with proxy.

Basically proxy should:

- initiate SSL connection with legitimate website
- issue self-signed certificate
- pass data received from legitimate website to browser
- capture requests issued by browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/download.html) is one of the best.

Answer (score 9):

If you want a stand alone app, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) works nicely with SSL capture enabled.

Comment: Does it works also like proxy? If browser is on machine A and proxy is on machine B?

Comment: Yes it does, you can enable remote connections in the settings

Answer (score 1):

I typically use [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) - it seems to do everything you would need. Or if you want to do more, the entire [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) does a huge amount. It is my first goto tool for the automated part of a security assessment, allowing me to spider an application, run scripts, test for particular vulnerabilities, and even an element for fuzzing/sequencing.